# Trying to redirect with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I'm very new to javascript and I'm trying to make different events occur depending on types of input. I have the following in my html header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm(){
    var val=document.getElementsByName("destination");
    if (val == "deprecated"){
      window.location="http://website.com/";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Then in the body, I have the following:

```
<select name="destination">
<option value="current_builds">Current Builds</option>
<option value="deprecated">Deprecated Files</option>
<option value="mailing_list">Mailing List</option>
</select><br/>
<input type="button" value="next >" onClick="validateForm()" />
```

This however doesn't do anything. It just stays on the same page. I also tried wrapping it inside a form tag by saying:

```
<form name="my_form" onSubmit="validateForm()">
...
</form>
```

and then having matching javascript:

```
var val = document.forms["my_form"]["destination"].value
```

But this didn't work either.

Anyone see what the issue is?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed your function and tested it:

```
function validateForm(){
    var val=document.getElementsByName("destination");
    var theSelectedOption = val[0].options[val[0].selectedIndex].value;
    if (theSelectedOption == "deprecated"){
      window.location="http://website.com/";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you give a little explanation please so I know for the future? Like how do you know to choose val[0] as opposed to val[1] or something? Would there be a time when val[1] would be chosen and can you give me an example where this would occur? Also, why do I need the .selectedIndex part?

Comment: The `getElementsByName("destination")` method accesses all elements having like a name "destination", it returns an array of all the elements found. Here val[0] is the first element found, val[1] is for the second element found in your html (if there is one)... The selectedIndex sets or returns the index of the selected option in the dropdown list.
See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp

Comment: from the name `getElementsByName`, its `Elements` is plural meaning there could be more than one elements having that name, so a collection in form of array is returned. On the other hand `getElementById` is singular, one element is expected to be returned

Comment: Ah, makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, another quick question: could we have done:
var theSelectedOption = val[0].value because when you hit the button, doesn't it automatically return the value of the selected index?

Comment: yes of course you can use it, it returns the value of the currently selected option. See http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-59351919

Answer (score 3):

You need to grab the value from the selected element. Since document.getElementsByName returns an array, try using this

```
var val = ​document.getElementsByName("destination")​​​​​[0].value
```

Comment: Wow that works. But I don't understand why. Why does it get submitted as an array? Is there more than 1 element in that array?

Comment: no there's one element, the 0 element.
and yes, as in an array

Comment: Well, think about that for a sec. You're calling getElementsByName. That's Element_S_, as in multiiple. Javascript will return to you all elements with the given name, therefore, it returns them in an array. Even if it's just one element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value from the selected option. Like so:

```
var index = document.getElementsByName("destination").selectedIndex; 
var val=document.getElementsByName("destination").options[index].value;
```

That will retrieve the value of the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the href attribute, you want to use:

```
window.location.href = 'URL';
```

Answer (score 0):

do the following

```
<select name="destination" id="destination">
```

Your JavaScript

```
val=document.getElementsById("destination").value;
```

Put an `alert(val)` in your `if` to see if ever evaluates to true

Answer (score 0):

Try it with id's instead of name, an id is a unique element. Javascript supports

```
var destination = document.getElementById("destination");
if (destination.options[destination.selectedIndex].value == "deprecated"){
  window.location="http://website.com/";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="destination">
    <option value="current_builds">Current Builds</option>
    <option value="deprecated">Deprecated Files</option>
    <option value="mailing_list">Mailing List</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="button" value="next &gt;" onclick="javascript:validateForm();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with a little bit of jquery

[Redirect using drop down](http://jsfiddle.net/slfede/Pkas9/)

```
<form name="my_form">
  <select id="destination">
    <option value="current_builds">Current Builds</option>
    <option value="deprecated">Deprecated Files</option>
    <option value="mailing_list">Mailing List</option>
  </select><br/>
  <input type="button" value="next >" id="submit">
</form>
```

​

```
$('#submit').click(
   function validateForm(){
   var e = document.getElementById("destination");
   var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

   if (val == "deprecated"){
     window.location="http://website.com/";
   }
});
```